# Mapstruct and limiting the depth of object mapping

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am currently using MapStruct to map data transfer objects (DTOs) to entities and vice-versa. I noticed the latest stable release does not offer "out of the box" functionality for detecting cycles however the RC1 version does with the `@Context` annotation.

At the moment, MapStruct works great however due to the way these DTOs and entities are setup in this app, it may map objects to a depth that is unnecessary (at times it would map a significant portion of the database from just one object).

Answer (score 0):

"Out of the box" support will most probably mean that you will have to have a runtime dependency on MapStruct things. We do not want to have that, therefore the `@Context` has been added to the next `1.2.0` release.

In order to avoid unnecessary mapping at certain levels you will have to explicitly use `@Mapping(ignore = true)` and the appropriate `target` or `source`.

There is also a feature request [#1152](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1152) that would allow the user to explicitly block some accessors of being accessed and thus always ignored. Something similar as the jackson `@JsonIgnore`.

Comment: We have implemented `@Mapping(target = "...", ignore = true)` on troublesome properties, however some parts of the app will still need some properties of ignored Entity/Dto. This is a workaround, but doesn't truly solve the problem.

Comment: You can define different mappers / methods that won't have those properties ignored. What would solve your problem?